# Will the cache work after I format a USB HDD with ext4?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, cache

I have a USB HDD. With `fdisk -l` I get:

```
Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc2  264192 9767540735 9767276544  4.6T Microsoft basic data
```

The 128MB of `sdc1` correspond to the HDD cache. My plan was formatting `sdc2` with `ext4`. Easy:

```
# mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc2
```

Would formatting `sdc2` impact the cache or it would still be used in the same way?

Comment: The reason to use ext4 is the convenience of keeping file metadata, permissions, etc. However, not at the inconvenience of performance loss.

Comment: How do they correspond to the "HDD cache"? What kind of cache are you talking about in general?

Comment: The rightmost column in the table at the end: https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/internal-hard-drives/laptop-hard-drives/barracuda-2-5/

Comment: That's a RAM cache; I highly doubt that it would correspond to any visible partition, or any accessible LBA at all. It would kind of defeat the whole point.

Comment: So I thought. I was not expecting to find it there, but there it is. I cannot mount it, which makes sense. Technically, it should work based on HDD sectors, not files, and therefore the format of the main partition should have no impact. _However_, I don't know how things work these days, everything changes, and SSHDs (or Intel RST or IDK) may have inspired fancier approaches. So here I am asking before making the cache potentially unusable, just to be safe.

Comment: Are you assuming it's the cache just because it's a 128 MB partition?

Comment: It's an uncanny coincidence. Could be anything else, like disk space to flush the RAM to for fail-safe guarantees. Which, in hindsight, makes more sense.

Comment: It is an uncanny coincidence, but it still doesn't make any sense to me because 2) data in the RAM write cache already has its designated place to go, 1) any such firmware-managed space would simply be inaccessible to the host OS at all. (Just like the reallocated sector reserve, for example.) I guess there is one way to find out -- dump contents of sdc1 to a file, use the disk for a few days, then dump its contents again and check if they changed.

Comment: That is a great idea, I will try. Thank you.